# TypeError: XXX undefined with AngularJS $inject Property annotation

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, grid, angular-ui, angular-ui-grid

### Angular UI Grid Get Cell Vaule

I am using angular grid ui and I am trying to get the vaule of cell based on the row and column using getCellValue.

I am getting the error

Unable to get property '$$undefined' of undefined or null reference

How do I get the vaule from a cell based on the row and the column?

```
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.resizeColumns','ui.grid.pinning','ui.grid.grouping',
    'ui.grid.moveColumns','ui.grid.exporter','ui.grid.selection','ui.grid.selection', 'ui.grid.cellNav']).controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

    MainCtrl.$inject = ['$http', 'uiGridConstants','$interval','$scope'];
    
    function MainCtrl($http, uiGridConstants,$scope) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.gridOptions = { //vm
          exporterMenuCsv: true,
          enableGridMenu:true,
          onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
            vm.gridApi = gridApi; //vm
          }
        };
    
        $http.get('/getProjects')
          .then(function(response) {
            //Loop through the response
            //If the vaule is 255 set the color of the cell to ect.
            var responseData = response.data
              console.log(vm.gridApi.grid.getCellValue(1,1));
              //console.log(responseData[i].Iuk)
         });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The injection array doesn't match the parameters of the function:

```
MainCtrl.$inject = ['$http', 'uiGridConstants','$interval','$scope'];

function MainCtrl($http, uiGridConstants,$scope) {
```

From the Docs:

> ## `$inject` Property Annotation
>
> When using this type of annotation, take care to keep the annotation array in sync with the parameters in the function declaration.
>
> [— AngularJS Developer Guide - Dependency Injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

This problem can be avoided by using [Implicit Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#implicit-annotation). Tools like [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate) let you use implicit dependency annotations in your app and automatically add array annotations prior to minifying.